# UITableViewCell strategy

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After creating several apps, I'm questioning myself with the use of UITableViewCell. In most project, I keep creating files for cells which doesn't contain anything else than a combination of UILabels / UIImageView / UISwitch...It's a pain to create these files over and over and there isn't much logic in there.

I'm currently starting the creation of a small pod to help me on factor UIKit code on different projects and was wondering how I could optimize this particular subject.

I first thought about having some default classes in that fashion:

```
public class OneLabelCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}

public class TwoLabelsCell : OneLabelCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
}

public class OneLabelOneImageCell : OneLabelCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

And then, by going all the way, I thought of having just a single class that would cover all my needs:

```
public class MagicCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var firstImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var firstSwitch: UISwitch!

    [...]
}
```

What's your opinion on this? What are the pros/cons of each method?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you using storyboard?. You can use `title` label of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you are truly reusing the EXACT same cell types across many, many projects, you could make a pod out of it.

However, I would not do that. Each project has the possibility of needing specific changes made to it. In this case, making those files for each project makes sense, and I don't think you would gain much from having a custom UITableViewCell class.

Maybe it seems like you are wasting time/resources making all those individual files for each project. Creating a pod may help reduce the waste, but only if the cells have very little to no differences between projects.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a small pod to put some pieces of code I use frequently across different projects, it's not a pod dedicated to UITableViewCells. The average project I do have 5 to 10 custom cells and I'd be really happy to avoid creating similar files every time.

Comment: If you are just adding to an existing pod, then it's not as bad. So now, I'd say again that as long as those 5 to 10 custom cells don't require much editing between projects, then go for it and add them to your pod.